# Firebase Real Time Database solo funciona dentro del editor de unity

Tags: base-de-datos, firebase

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en unity en el cual uso firebase y haciendo las pruebas en el editor de unity logro recibir datos pero una vez que lo intento en mi telefono no funciona. No salen errores ni crashea, solo no muestra datos. Dejo un ejemplo:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Unity.Editor;

public class LoadData : MonoBehaviour{
    Text a;
    string x;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("el link de la base de datos");
        Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase dbInstance = Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance;
        dbInstance.GetReference("Niveles/1/1/Nombre").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsFaulted) {
                // Handle the error...
            } else if (task.IsCompleted) {
                a = GetComponent<Text>();
                DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                x = snapshot.Value.ToString();
                a.text = x;
            }
        });
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Algunos problemas que podrian estar pasando. Las reglas de seguridad de firebase no te dejan acceder a los datos quizas si no estas autenticado. No añadiste el permiso de internet en el manifest para realtimedatabase